# SPD-Workflow: how to send an email to username stored in variable

Tags: designer-workflow

How do I send an email to a user whose username is stored in a string variable?

Do I need to lookup the email address first? how it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

If the email address is stored in a variable, you just supply the email action with that variable in the To field.

Comment: The username is stored in a Variable, not the email address. How do I  determine the email address?

Comment: In SPD create a variable with String type. And populate it with the Person field or the field where you get the user from, and select email address as type.